# How to properly moq ExecuteQuery method within DataContext?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I'm having a difficult time trying to understand how to appropriately return mocked data from a simulated database call in a unit test.

Here's an example method I want to unit test (**GetBuildings**):

```
public class BuildingService : IBuildingService {

    public IQueryable<Building> GetBuildings(int propertyId)
    {
        IQueryable<Building> buildings;

        // Execution path for potential exception thrown
        // if (...) throw new SpecialException();

        // Another execution path...
        // if (...) ...

        using (var context = DataContext.Instance())
        {
            var Params = new List<SqlParameter>
            {
                new SqlParameter("@PropertyId", propertyId)
            };

            // I need to return mocked data here...
            buildings = context
              .ExecuteQuery<Building>(System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, "dbo.Building_List", Params.ToArray<object>())
              .AsQueryable();


        }

        return buildings;
    }

}
```

So **GetBuildings** calls a stored procedure.

So I need to mock the DataContext, that of which I can override and set a testable instance. So what happens here is, in the above example `DataContext.Instance()` does return the mocked object.

```
[TestFixture]
public class BuildingServiceTests
{

    private Mock<IDataContext> _mockDataContext;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup() {
        _mockDataContext = new Mock<IDataContext>();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown() {
        ...
    }

    [Test]
    public void SomeTestName() {

        _mockDataContext.Setup(r => 
            r.ExecuteQuery<Building>(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "someSproc"))
            .Returns(new List<Building>() { new Building() { BuildingId = 1, Title = "1" }}.AsQueryable());

      DataContext.SetTestableInstance(_mockDataContext.Object); 
        var builings = BuildingService.GetBuildings(1, 1);

      // Assert...

    }
```

Please ignore some of the parameters, like `propertyId`. I've stripped those out and simplified this all. I simply can't get the `ExecuteQuery` method to return any data.

All other simple peta-poco type methods I can mock without issue (i.e. Get, Insert, Delete).

**Update**

`DataContext.Instance` returns the active instance of the DataContext class, if exists, and if not exists, returns a new one. So the method of test under question returns the mocked instance.

Comment: `DataContext.Instance()` is what is being called within the method under test. It is not shown in the example above. seeing as the context is what needs to be mocked. there should be an entry point to be able to access/set that value. Unable to tell how that instance is provided based on the current information shown. provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Nkosi Apologies. I've updated my question. Does this help clarify? `DataContext.Instance()` is properly returning the Moq. I've verified this. I just can't get ExecuteQuery to return the data that I want for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the mock to return data is needs to be set up to behave as expected given a provided input.

currently in the method under test it is being called like this

```
buildings = context
  .ExecuteQuery<Building>(System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, "dbo.Building_List", Params.ToArray<object>())
  .AsQueryable();
```

Yet in the test the mock context is being setup like

```
_mockDataContext.Setup(r => 
    r.ExecuteQuery<Building>(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "someSproc"))
    .Returns(new List<Building>() { new Building() { BuildingId = 1, Title = "1" }}.AsQueryable());
```

Note what the mock is told to expect as parameters.

The mock will only behave as expected when provided with those parameters. Otherwise it will return null.

Consider the following example of how the test can be exercised based on the code provided in the original question.

```
[Test]
public void SomeTestName() {
    //Arrange
    var expected = new List<Building>() { new Building() { BuildingId = 1, Title = "1" }}.AsQueryable();
    _mockDataContext
        .Setup(_ => _.ExecuteQuery<Building>(CommandType.StoredProcedure, It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>()))
        .Returns(expected);

    DataContext.SetTestableInstance(_mockDataContext.Object);
    var subject = new BuildingService();

    //Act
    var actual = subject.GetBuildings(1);

    // Assert...
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected, actual);
}
```

That said, the current design of the system under test is tightly coupled to a static dependency which is a code smell and makes the current design follow some bad practices.

The static `DataContext` which is currently being used as a factory should be refactored as such,

```
public interface IDataContextFactory {
    IDataContext CreateInstance();
}
```

and explicitly injected into dependent classes instead of calling the static factory method

```
public class BuildingService : IBuildingService {

    private readonly IDataContextFactory factory;

    public BuildingService(IDataContextFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory
    }

    public IQueryable<Building> GetBuildings(int propertyId) {
        IQueryable<Building> buildings;

        using (var context = factory.CreateInstance()) {
            var Params = new List<SqlParameter> {
                new SqlParameter("@PropertyId", propertyId)
            };

            buildings = context
              .ExecuteQuery<Building>(System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, "dbo.Building_List", Params.ToArray<object>())
              .AsQueryable();
        }

        return buildings;
    }
}
```

This will allow for a proper mock to be created in injected into the subject under test without using a static workaround hack.

```
[Test]
public void SomeTestName() {
    //Arrange
    var expected = new List<Building>() { new Building() { BuildingId = 1, Title = "1" }}.AsQueryable();
    _mockDataContext
        .Setup(_ => _.ExecuteQuery<Building>(CommandType.StoredProcedure, It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>()))
        .Returns(expected);

    var factoryMock = new Mock<IDataContextFactory>();
    factoryMock
        .Setup(_ => _.CreateInstance())
        .Returns(_mockDataContext.Object);

    var subject = new BuildingService(factoryMock.Object);

    //Act
    var actual = subject.GetBuildings(1);

    // Assert...
    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your thorough answer. I'm trying this now, although torn based on the other answer about not mocking `DataContext`. But still appears this answers the question. I'll report back!

Comment: In my case I do need to mock DataContext for complicated reasons, and given this answers my original question, this is the one I accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Do not mock `DataContext`. Because mocking `DataContext` will produce tests tightly coupled to the implementation details of `DataContext`. And you will be forced to change tests for every change in the code even behavior will remain same.

Instead introduce a "DataService" interface and mock it in the tests for `BuildingService`.

```
public interface IDataService
{
    IEnumerable<Building> GetBuildings(int propertyId)
}
```

Then, you can tests implementation of `IDataService` agains real database as part of integration tests or tests it agains database in memory.

If you can test with "InMemory" database (EF Core or Sqlite) - then even better -> write tests for `BuildingService` against actual implementation of `DataContext`.

In tests you should mock only external resources (web service, file system or database) or only resources which makes tests slow.

Not mocking other dependencies will save you time and give freedom while you refactoring your codebase.

After update:

Based on the updated question, where `BuildingService` have some execution path - you can still testing `BuildingService` and abstract data related logic to the `IDataService`.

For example below is `BuildingService` class

```
public class BuildingService
{
    private readonly IDataService _dataService;

    public BuildingService(IDataService dataService)
    {
         _dataService = dataService;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Building> GetBuildings(int propertyId)
    {
        if (propertyId < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Negative id not allowed");
        }

        if (propertyId == 0)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<Building>();
        }

        return _myDataService.GetBuildingsOfProperty(int propertyId);
    }
}
```

In tests you will create a mock for `IDataService` and pass it to the constructor of `BuildingService`

```
var fakeDataService = new Mock<IDataContext>();
var serviceUnderTest = new BuildingService(fakeDataService);
```

Then you will have tests for:

```
"Should throw exception when property Id is negative"  
"Should return empty collection when property Id equals zero"
"Should return collection of expected buildings when valid property Id is given"
```

For last test case you will mock `IDataService` to return expected building only when correct `propertyId` is given to `_dataService.GetBuildingsOfProperty` method

Comment: Part of the issue, or lack of understanding that I'm facing is, the `GetBuildings()` method has a couple execution paths that can throw exceptions prior to the database call. I should have included them in my example, but was focused on the original issue. The `IBuildingService` interface I can easily mock like your example - in fact it has the very method you are showing. But then I'm unable to test the possible executions paths (errors thrown), which is why I was relying on mocking data context. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I've updated my example to show what I mean. If I mock the interface which contracts the method, I'm unsure of how to test the execution paths.

Comment: @user1447679 - check updated answer. Idea is you will still wright tests for `BuildingService` but instead of using `DataContext` you will wrap `DataContext` in the `IDataService`. If you execute more then one query you can create own method in interface for every query